# Set up wordpress multi-region site

Tags: wordpress

Does someone have experience with setting up a multi regional site in wordpress? I need to set up 9 languages in 15 regions, which is kind of a lot. I don't think that common plugins like WPML are capable of that amount. URL structure should be the following.

```
mycompany.com/en-gb/
mycompany.com/en-us/
mycompany.com/en-au/
mycompany.com/en-de/
mycompany.com/de-gb/
mycompany.com/de-us/
mycompany.com/de-au/
mycompany.com/de-de/
```

Comment: "wordpress localization" would be the keyterm you should be looking for on Google

Comment: Did you try WPML? [Looks like](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/how-many-languages/) it [should be possible](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/number-of-languages-limitation/).